# Connect GeoServer to ESRI PostgreSQL database

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I want to connect to an Enterprise geodatabase in PostgreSQL from GeoServer. The ESRI GDB is not running a SDE instance. Can I do a direct connection from GeoServer? What is the right way to put the connection values in GeoServer? Host, Instance?

I tried to connect using Postgis and Postgis JNDI connections and I didn't get to connect. I modified the context.xml following https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/tomcat-jndi/tomcat-jndi.html

The postgres database hasn't got postgis extensión, Doesn't it mind to connect as Postgis?

Comment: There is no difference between connecting to a PostgreSQL EGDB and a non-geodatabase PG instance.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It's my first time in this site